# new line separator doesn't work for group_concat function

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I have a string `(name lastname,name2 lastname2...)` with values from a database table and I want to display it
like:

```
name lastname
name2 lastname2..
```

I use group_concat function it works for commma separators but I need new line separator.

```
group_concat(concat_ws(' ',users.firstname, users.lastname) SEPARATOR '<br>') as contacts_name
```

Comment: I think you forgot to include the definition of "doesn't work" (what does your query do that you don't expect, or what does it not do that you would expect?)

Comment: it displays name lastname <br>, name2 lastname<br>

Comment: And what would you like it to display? Isn't that what you specifically asked for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this : `"\r\n"` with double quotes, not simple

Comment: it works but it adds one space additionally in next row