# mysql select table drop list order by in group

Tags: php, mysql

I want to group by and in group show order by list 
what can I do?

[image]

I want to view like this

[image]

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
where num='1'
group by num (select serial From my table order by serial ASC )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing I understand correctly, that you want `num` in ascending order, and within that `serial` in descending order, then this query will work for you:

```
SELECT * from mytable
ORDER BY num, serial DESC
```

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a80ab/1)

**EDIT**

Using the [Group_Concat()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) function you can concatenate the `serial` values:

```
SELECT num, name, prud, 
GROUP_CONCAT(serial ORDER BY serial DESC separator "\r\n")as GROUPED 
FROM a
GROUP BY num
```

[Second working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a80ab/24)

You may have to adjust the `separator` in order to get your values to print on  a new line. For example you may opt to use `'\n'` or `"<br>"`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701156/group-concat-have-values-display-in-a-new-line-on-the-browser) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875870/new-line-separator-doesnt-work-for-group-concat-function) may help you address this issue.

Comment: i want group col (num) and if num have more serials in row want to show the serials in one group

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: thank you  .. am useing this and working with me :)